# How would I use Chebyshev's inequality for this problem?

Tags: statistics, chebyshev-function

A probability distribution has a mean of 50 and a standard deviation of $2$. Use Chebyshev's inequality to find the minimum probability that an outcome is between $42$ and $58$.

~~

How would I use Chebyshev's inequality for this problem? Any similar questions, feel free to link it in the comment section, as well as any questions. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A big hint:

$$42 < X < 58$$

is the same as

$$|X-50|<8$$

Comment: Please can you explain the chebyshev inequality here? I wasn't able to do it. I really want to know how it works here and how this can be used to answer the above question.

Comment: We have $P(|X-\mu| \ge k\sigma) \le \frac1{k^2}$, that is $P(|X-\mu| \le k\sigma) \ge 1-\frac1{k^2}$

Comment: What would be the minimum probability that an outcome is between 42 and 58? Is it 1-1/k**2? What would be the K value here?

Comment: here $k\sigma =8$ and we know $\sigma$, hence we can solve for $k$.

Comment: ok but can I know how is `k * sigma = 8` ? It isn't mentioned in the question or is there any calculation behind it?

Comment: $|X-50|<8$ that's where the $8$ comes from.

Comment: That's confusing how is `42 < X < 58` equals to `|X-50| < 8`? Sorry I'm really confused and I couldn't find anything that's helpful so far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87940/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-sai-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Let $X$ be the r.v. the problem is referencing. Then
$$
\Bbb{P}( 42 \leq X \leq 58 ) = \Bbb{P}(|X-50| \leq 8). 
$$
Now, use Chebechev's inequality here.